# How to read .shp files in Databricks notebook

Tags: python, azure-databricks, geopandas

I am working on a problem where I need to plot output on a Map.
In past I was able to do it using `geopandas`.
However this does not work in `databricks-notebook`.
I tried to look at alternative but couldn't find any on web.

Pages I looked in to:
[GeoPandas Notebook](https://databricks.com/notebooks/geopandas-notebook.html)
[Processing Geospatial Data at Scale With Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/12/05/processing-geospatial-data-at-scale-with-databricks.html)

In the second link it mentions that we can read `.shp` flies through `scala`
however it does not mention what `sc` in `ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD` stands for?

```
%scala
var spatialRDD = new SpatialRDD[Geometry]
spatialRDD = ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD(sc, "/ml/blogs/geospatial/shapefiles/nyc")

var rawSpatialDf = Adapter.toDf(spatialRDD,spark)
rawSpatialDf.createOrReplaceTempView("rawSpatialDf") //DataFrame now available to SQL, Python, and R
```

Answer (score 0):

In the databricks notebook:

- Install geopandas: `%pip install geopandas`
- Import geopandas: `import geopandas as gpd`
- The path have to use "File Api Format": `/dbfs/databricks/folderName`
- Create the gdf: `sdf = gpd.read_file('/dbfs/databricks/folderName')`

Comment: Not sure why but I am facing the following error with the solution above: DriverError: /FileStore/myfile.shp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Below steps to read the .shp files in Databricks notebook

1. Drag the .zip file folder to Databricks data section and once the notepad opens up, put the below code in the python notebook.
2. Inside the .zip folder, the shape file name is tl_2020_us_state.shp
   Replace this name with your shape file.

   import geopandas
   from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
   import os
   from dotenv import load_dotenv
   import re
   import io
   import fiona;
   import fsspec
   from zipfile import ZipFile
   import requests
   from **future** import print_function
   import zipfile
   from io import StringIO
   import shapefile

   myshp = open("tl_2020_us_state.shp", "rb")
   mydbf = open("tl_2020_us_state.dbf", "rb")
   shpfile_rd = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, shx=None, dbf=mydbf)
   shpfile_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file('tl_2020_us_state.shp')
   shpfile_df.head()

   #for plotting the map
   shpfile_df.plot()

Answer (score 0):

```
# Define the variables and the values
zipfile_name = 'tl_2020_us_state.zip'
shapefile_name = 'tl_2020_us_state.shp'
shapefile_url = 'https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020/STATE/' + zipfile_name

#Define the absolute path of the shapefile out of the zip file in local file
shapefile_path = os.path.abspath(zipfile_name)

## Download a shapefile, upload into local directory
# download the shapefile to the shapefile path
with requests.get(shapefile_url) as r:
    with open(shapefile_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)              

# unzip the file
with zipfile.ZipFile(shapefile_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(os.curdir)
    #print(os.curdir)    
    
# set home directory and download data
et.data.get_data("spatial-vector-lidar") ## for earthpy.io.DATA_URLS
os.chdir(os.path.join(et.io.HOME, 'earth-analytics')) ## works on Mac or Linux   ## Set your working directory in Python using os.chdir()

## import shapefile using geopandas
plot_locations_df = geopandas.read_file(
                          os.path.join(
                          os.curdir, 
                          shapefile_name))

## view the top 6 lines of attribute table of data
plot_locations_df.head(20)

#print (plot_locations_df)
#plot_locations_df.head()
#plot_locations_df.plot()
#plot_locations_df
```